# Can a tag be read by more then one reader at the same time? and can a reader read more then one tag at the same time?

Tags: networking, protocols, network-protocols, rfid, network-security

Can a tag be read by more then one reader at the same time? 
And can a reader read more then one tag at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to both your question is Yes, depending on what you mean by "at the same time". Because tag reading is done very fast (at least in inventory mode) it would seem that it all happens at the same time, but basically the operation is sequential: one tag gets read in a few milliseconds, than another is read in a few milliseconds, and in an inventory cycle which last for about a few hundred milliseconds you can have 10 or more tags returned to you. The operations are done at the same time in the same meaning that a processor can execute multiple tasks at the same time.
The operation of reading the same tag with more than one reader is useful location applications, and reading more than one tag with the same reader is used in logistics, when inventorying bulk items. If you need to read other type of memory from the tag (not the tag ID), the tag must be selected first (so much slower, but the principle stays the same).